# Laravel migration return SQL error but SQL is valid and it works

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

I have migration which works locally but fails on production with error:

```
Migrating: 2024_03_19_145356_tasks

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'send_before' (SQL: create table `tasks` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `subscription_id` bigint unsigned not null, `send_after` timestamp not null, `send_before` timestamp not null, `sent_at` timestamp null comment 'null = not sent', `failed_at` timestamp null, `delivered` tinyint(1) null default '0' comment '0 - not delivered, 1 - delivered, null - unknown', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I'm failing miserably to debug because SQL is valid and in fact works fine on production when run via phpMyAdmin or terminal:

```
create table `tasks` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `subscription_id` bigint unsigned not null, `send_after` timestamp not null, `send_before` timestamp not null, `sent_at` timestamp null comment 'null = not sent', `failed_at` timestamp null, `delivered` tinyint(1) null default '0' comment '0 - not delivered, 1 - delivered, null - unknown', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

**2024_03_19_145356_tasks.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Tasks extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('subscription_id')->constrained('subscriptions')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamp('send_after')->index();
            $table->timestamp('send_before')->index();
            $table->timestamp('sent_at')->nullable()->index()->comment('null = not sent');
            $table->timestamp('failed_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('delivered')->default(0)->comment('0 - not delivered, 1 - delivered, null - unknown')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tasks');
    }
}
```

Server version: 5.5.60-MariaDB MariaDB Server

PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2023 14:45:16) ( NTS )

Laravel Framework 8.83.27

**UPDATED 1**

Added `dump(\DB::select("SELECT @@version, @@sql_mode"));` into migration and I found out that `sql_mode` during migration has this `sql_mode` settings:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#1958
    +"@@version": "5.5.60-MariaDB"
    +"@@sql_mode": "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
  }
]
```

**UPDATED (SOLVED?)**

I located the issue. I don't want to pretend like I have a clue what is happening, so I'll say it as it is:
The problem hits when migration has more then one column type `timestamp` which `is not nullable`. Here are some example:

Works:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('test1');
    $table->timestamp('test2')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('test3')->nullable();
});
```

Error `1067 Invalid default value for 'test2'`:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('test1');
    $table->timestamp('test2');
    $table->timestamp('test3')->nullable();
});
```

Works:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('test1')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('test2')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('test3');
});
```

Error `1067 Invalid default value for 'test2'`:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('test1');
    $table->timestamp('test2');
});
```

Works:

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('test1')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('test2');
    $table->timestamp('test3')->nullable();
});
```

And... if I use `dateTime` it always works. So... The issue is kind of solved although I have no clue what is going on and I'd like to know

Comment: Can you please run this query in both your development environment and production environment, and add it to your post above: `SELECT @@version, @@sql_mode;`

Comment: @BillKarwin, MariaDB version is in the end of the post. sql_mode is empty when I run it with phpMyAdmin. But the SQL in question works via phpMyAdmin as well, so it feels like it might be misleading to say that sql_mode is empty.

Comment: But is the version and the sql_mode the same in production as it is in your local development instance? That's what I'm asking to confirm.

Comment: Also for what it's worth — MariaDB 5.5 is ancient. It was released in 2013, and [support ended in 2020](https://endoflife.date/mariadb). PHP 7.4 is also [past its extended support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Legecy :( Anyway... You was asking about local environment. It is different and it is very much up to date. But the trick is: it doesn't seems to metter because prod can handle the same sql while no Laravel PDO connection involved.

Comment: You really should run the same version of all software in development as is running in production where you will eventually deploy it. But I take your point that it is puzzling why it works when you run the SQL directly, but not from Laravel.

Comment: Could Laravel be setting a strict `sql_mode` just for its sessions? If it disallows zero date values, for example, and your timestamp column is defaulting to '0000-00-00' that could cause the error.

Comment: Updated the question. The issue is kind of solved although I have no clue what is going on and I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit default for timestamp columns (that is, the default when you don't define a default explicitly) is complex. And it behaves differently after the first timestamp column of a table. It's super weird.

The first timestamp column is automatically given the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` options, if you don't specify any default, and `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` is false.

Subsequent timestamp columns don't get these options automatically. The implicit default for a `NOT NULL` timestamp is the "default default" timestamp value, which is 0.

But Laravel apparently sets a session `sql_mode` that includes `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`, which makes the 0 value of timestamp invalid.

So your options are:

- Allow your timestamp column to be nullable.
- Declare an explicit `DEFAULT` for the column.
- Figure out how to change Laravel's idea of the best `sql_mode` to allow zeroes in dates. I don't recommend this, because dates with zeroes aren't real dates. It's a good idea to disallow them.